# Runtime Exception in @RequestMapping annotated Controller - which HTTP Response Code?

Tags: java, spring-boot, http-headers

For a Spring Boot application, running Spring Boot 1.5.2, I  have a handleRequest() method that looks similar to the following:

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/my/path/endpoint", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = { "text/*", "application/json" })
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.Accepted) 
public void handleRequest(@RequestBody String body, @RequestHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE) Object contentType, @RequestHeader HttpHeaders headers) throws IllegalArgumentException, JsonProcessingException {
    if( //I'm missing a required header ) {
        throw new CustomExceptionThatExtendsRuntimeException("missing my header"); 
    }
    /* 
        do more stuff here
    */ 
}
```

What would be the HTTP response code returned in the case where my IF statement is true and I throw a RuntimeException in my method body?

Comment: What did it return when you ran your code and checked?

Comment: I can't tell because there is a lot of network stuff upstream, and I can't get to the actual return code.  I will probably end up mocking up a simple example, though, and test to find out.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring will throw a `500 Internal Server Error`, because an exception occurred and it wasn't properly handled.

The `HandleExceptionResolver` is used to resolve exceptions thrown during the request lifecycle.

If an exception occurs, the `DispatcherServlet` delegates a chain of `HandlerExceptionResolver` beans to resolve the exception and provide, typically, an error response. Since Spring doesn't know how to handle your custom exception, a HTTP 500 will be thrown indicating that an internal error has occurred.

You can create a bean of `HandlerExceptionResolver` and register to your application context, or either use a `ControllerAdvice` or `RestControllerAdvice` if you want to handle these exceptions.